# Repeated integration by parts for $x^4\cdot\cosh(x/2)$

Tags: integration

Can I use repeated integration by parts/Tabular Integration to integrate $$x^4\cdot\cosh(x/2)$$

I have used it but I am not sure if I am allowed to.

Comment: Welcome to MSE , plz use Tex, Mathjax also provide motivation and stuff , follows the guidelines of MSE

Comment: That said, whether you're "allowed to", other than the fact you can, in fact, do it ($\cosh(x)$ has a known derivative, so just repeatedly differentiate $x^4$ in the process and it'll eventually end), is more a matter to discuss with your instructor than us.

Comment: Hint: using integration by parts four times gives$$\int x^4f^{(5)}dx=x^4f^{(4)}-4x^3f^{(3)}+12x^2f''-24xf'+24f+C.$$Take $f=2^5\sinh(x/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.The validity of integration by parts when $f,g$ both have continuous derivatives comes from $(fg)'=f'g+g'f,$ which implies that $f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx$ is an anti-derivative of $g'(x)f(x).$ E.g. when $f(x)=x^4$ and $g(x)=2\sinh(x/2).$